Querying SQL - Whether an ID is pointing to an existing item or not?
I have the following issue: I have three entities:

Problems
Tasks
Objects

Their relations:

A Problem knows about its Task
A Task knows about its Object

There are no more relations in between them.
So: a Problem has a Task, and this Task has an Object.
I would like to query Problems which have a Task, which Task has an Object which is not present in the database.
Example:
A Problem has a Task, the Task has an Object with id = 10, but this id = 10 Object is not in the database in the Object Table.
As of right now this is my attempt:
SELECT * 
FROM Problems 
INNER JOIN Tasks ON Tasks.Id = problems.TaskId 
                 AND tasks.objectID
... [MISSING PART HERE? I don't know.]


You can use NOT EXISTS

Solution: Use foreign keys!

There are no rdbms tags in the question, but the code below should work as is on most SQL versions. It was tested with Oracle, though.
One of the options to do it is using Left Join and Where condition for nulls:
--  S a m p l e    D a t a :

/*  problems table:
ID  PROBLEM_NAME   TASK_ID
--  ------------  --------
1   Problem 1            3
2   Problem 2            1
3   Problem 3            2    */

/*  tasks table
ID  TASK_NAME   OBJECT_ID
--  ----------  --------- 
 1  Task 1              1
 2  Task 2              2
 3  Task 3             10    */

/*  objects table
ID  OBJECT_NAME
--  -----------
 1  Object 1
 2  Object 2
 9  Object 9     */

Depending on what you want to select aside from missing object(s) here are two queries using Left Join to detect missing (null) objects:
--    S Q L   1 :     (all data)
Select     p.id as problem_id, p.problem_name, 
           t.id as task_id, t.task_name, 
           Coalesce(o.id, t.object_id) as object_id, o.object_name
From       problems p
Left Join  tasks t ON(t.id = p.task_id)
Left Join  objects o  ON(o.id = t.object_id)
Where      o.id Is Null

/*      R e s u l t    1 : 
PROBLEM_ID  PROBLEM_NAME    TASK_ID  TASK_NAME    OBJECT_ID  OBJECT_NAME
----------  --------------  -------  -----------  ---------  -----------
         1  Problem 1             3  Task 3              10  null           */

--    S Q L   2 :     (tasks and objects)
Select     t.id as task_id, t.task_name, 
           Coalesce(o.id, t.object_id) as object_id, o.object_name
From       tasks t 
Left Join  objects o  ON(o.id = t.object_id)
Where      o.id Is Null

/*      R e s u l t    2 : 
TASK_ID  TASK_NAME  OBJECT_ID  OBJECT_NAME
-------  ---------  ---------  -----------
      3  Task 3            10  null        */

See the fiddle here.

select p.problem_id
from problems as p
join tasks as t on p.problem_id=t.problem_id
where not exists
(
  select 1 from objects as ob where t.task_id=ob.task_id
)

Could you please try NOT EXISTS-solution
